# How to stop php script in Laravel when Axios request is cancelled?

Tags: php, laravel, axios

I'm making a live search using Laravel, VueJs and axios, so every time the user types a new word, the previous request will be cancelled. My problem is that even when I cancel the previous request using the cancel token (https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation), the php script is still running.

QUESTION: How can i stop the php script if the axios request has been cancelled?

**my Vuejs code**

```
fetchData(query) {
    if(cancel != undefined)
        cancel();   // cancel the previous request
    axios.get("http://sample-link", {
            cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
                cancel = c;
            }),
            params: {
                query : query
            }
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response);  
    }).catch(error => {console.log(error.message)})
}

...
```

**my php code**

```
class SearchController extends Controller {
    public function Search(Request $request)
    {
        $query = $request->input('query');
        $accounts = Accounts::search($query, null, true, true)->get();
        return response()->json($accounts);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: can't you wait for a moment before making call to the server? You can achieve this by using setTimeout function or you can use lodash debounce function.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly how the Axios cancellation works, but if the client disconnects the HTTP session (as it should) you could try using the [`ignore_user_abort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) setting.

```
public function Search(Request $request)
    {
        ignore_user_abort(false);
        $query = $request->input('query');
        $accounts = Accounts::search($query, null, true, true)->get();
        return response()->json($accounts);
    }
```

Other useful functions could be:

[`connection_status`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-status): Check the current status of the connection

[`connection_aborted`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.connection-aborted): Check if the connection has been canceled

---

I just want to add that your function does not seem very intensive, so I'm not sure how useful such a check is. As Tauqeer suggested in the comment, the usual approach in those situations is to apply a debounce to your javascript search function, in order to only fire the request when the user finished typing.

An example using [lodash](https://lodash.com/):

```
const search = (query) => {
    .. your axios request ...
}

const fetchData = _.debounce(search, 300)
```

Now you can just call `fetchData(query)` whenever the user types something and it will only send a request when the user stops typing for 300 milliseconds

Comment: I also had success adding a message ID of some sort. You increment it by one for every message sent and the backend responds with that message ID as well. Could also be the current timestamp, what you want. The javascript client then just throws away responses for old requests that it made.

Answer (score 0):

I just sorted out this problem by `connection_aborted()` in my controller code.

```
public function Search(Request $request)
{
    if (connection_aborted()) {
      $data = "Request cancelled";
      return $data;
    }
    $query = $request->input('query');
    $accounts = Accounts::search($query, null, true, true)->get();
    return response()->json($accounts);
}
```